# Is there a way to interactively monitor and EditText field in Android to corectly format what is entered

Tags: android, android-edittext, listener, currency, interactive

As the title asks, I want to correctly monitor an Edit Text field to format the entered numbers as a currency with a "." being l=placed or inserted after the last 2 digits of the cell.

In all as the user inputs the numbers and the field expands the EditText will reflect that the numbers that they entered will reflect as a currency, example below:

user enters "123456"

the EditText will reflect this as : "1234.56"
or even : "$1234.56"

I have tried a number of different techniques and believe that the section of code may need to be pleased within a TextWatcher which I currently have to clear the field if a user clicks on the field as well as the enabling of a button once a correct Boolean value is received after checking 2 fields.

the pieces of code that I will show below currently work, and I simply need the appropriate code and location to achieve the above stated needs.

This sections reflects my TextWatcher section:

```
        TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher(){
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    calcbtn.setEnabled(isready());
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {

}
    };
    numofpep.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher); //Links to the TextWatcher element for afterTextChanged function
    billtotal.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);//Links to the TextWatcher element for afterTextChanged function
    }
```

Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

cchinchoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something Like this should do it:

```
    @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String val = billTotal.getText().toString();
            String newStringContent = convertToDollarsAndCents(val);
            // change string to reflect your desired format
            billTotal.setText(newStringContent)
        }

        public String convertToDollarsAndCents(String val) {
          if(!val.contains(".") {
            if(val.length<=2) {
              return val+".00"
            }
            else {
               return val.subString(0, val.length-2)+"."+val.subString(val.length-2, val.length)
            }
          }
        }
```

The substring code might not be exactly right, but it ought to get it done with some tweaking.

The other option is to make your input a number input as you can configure an inputType for your EditText:

```
<EditText android:inputType="number" ... />
```

ANd put the onus on the user to indicate if they want cents or not.

Comment: looks good, but I am using the phone as the keyboard and as such there is no "." to let the user enter the "." that is the reason I want the interactivity. The other keyboard has a number of different characters that I would prefer to not have the user stress out to use, just numbers as it is simple to just punch in numbers starting from the left and not have to worry about the "." in a total.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the number keyboard has a "." on it

Comment: ok will check it out, I believe that the emulator showed the "." but when I tested it out on my handset it did not show the "." I will validate and let all know. thanks